# Select multiple column query for view by using where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get display id and name from a table into view. Where display id select by using where clause, upto now I am select only display id but now I want to select name also from same table.

old table was like this.

```
SELECT id, 
       (SELECT displayid 
        FROM   quickpay12.q_sponsortrack AS Q_SponsorTrack_1 
        WHERE  ( f1.transferto = f1.id )) AS TransferTo, 
       (SELECT displayid 
        FROM   quickpay12.q_sponsortrack AS Q_SponsorTrack 
        WHERE  ( f1.transferby = f1.id )) AS TransferBy, 
       descid, 
       credit, 
       debit, 
       description, 
       vdate, 
       balance, 
       wallettype, 
       sno 
FROM   quickpay12.f_transactionsummary_employee AS f1
```

Comment: can you make one sqlfiddle

Comment: Do you want to select the Display Id and Name columns from a table or a view? What's you table (or view) schema like?

Comment: Can you explain what relevance, the condition `f1.TransferBy = f1.id` has?

Comment: Hi Leo thanks for respond.Actually i am using view, in which i am select no. of columns from any no. of tables..In above i have already mention View query in which i m select only display id .Now i want to select name also from same table.so please post valuable response thank you......

Comment: F1 is return type of F_TransactionSummary_Employee(table name)so f1.transfer to is a column of this table and this column have id which is select the display id from Q_SponsorTrack..so i want Name also from Q_SponsorTrack..Thanks.....

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired answer? The question, phrased as it is, is a tad unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query to return all columns from all tables :

```
SELECT  f1.* ,
        Q_SponsorTrack_1.* ,
        Q_SponsorTrack.*
FROM    quickpay12.f_transactionsummary_employee AS f1
        LEFT JOIN quickpay12.q_sponsortrack AS Q_SponsorTrack_1 ON f1.transferto = Q_SponsorTrack_1.id
        LEFT JOIN quickpay12.q_sponsortrack AS Q_SponsorTrack ON f1.transferby = Q_SponsorTrack.id
```